# Vue.js - Firebase Auth cannot check correctly error message on Reset Password

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I am sending a password reset email to a user; when the number of request exceed a certain level, Firebase raise an error RESET_PASSWORD_EXCEED_LIMIT

I am trying to capture this message to alert the user ( account unavailable for a period of time ... cannot find how long..) but I cannot correctly grab the message ..

```
auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(this.email)
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log('ERROR: ', ...
```

**console.log('ERROR: ', error.message)**

```
  ERROR: {"error":{"code":400,"message":"RESET_PASSWORD_EXCEED_LIMIT","errors":[{"message":"RESET_PASSWORD_EXCEED_LIMIT","domain":"global","reason":"invalid"}]}}
```

**console.log('ERROR: ', error.message.error.message)**

ERROR:  undefined

**console.log('ERROR: ', error.message['"error"'])**

ERROR:  undefined

**console.log('ERROR: ', error.message['"error"'])**

```
ERROR:  undefined
```

It is a very strange error object format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the error message is stringified. You should use `JSON.parse`.